# Issue when using a shape as a button to accept user input from a shape text box

Tags: excel, vba, button, textbox, shapes

Hope somebody can help me with this Excel/VBA issue.

I have recently started replacing my active X controls with shape controls hoping for less issues and better performance, however I've stumbled across a strange issue when trying to accept user input from a shape textbox by clicking on a shape button.

I've setup a simple worksheet to demonstrate the problem, it simply has the following shapes;

1. Shape textbox used for input, I have locked the shape and unlocked the text.
2. Shape button with text for the button name, I have locked the shaped and locked the text.

When the button is clicked and the macro runs it copies the text from the textbox to cell A1

**Note:** I have protected the sheet except for cell A1

I want the user to input some text into the textbox then immediately click on the button to accept the input, the button will run a macro which will do something with the text.

I've discovered the macro only works when the outside area of the button is clicked, it won't work when the user clicks near the text which is embedded on the button and takes up most of the center area of that button. Also when I hover over the button the mouse pointer changes to a move pointer where text isn't present and for the area with the text it changes to a text pointer.

If I click out of the input text box first into a worksheet cell before clicking the button then it works as expected and the mouse pointer shows the expected link pointer.

[My test example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzdWX.png)

Below is the code assigned for the button macro;

```
Sub Test()

    Range("A1") = Sheet1.Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the shape locked so you're not clicking in the text-space, making that able to be edited?

Comment: Both shapes are locked. The text part is locked in the button but not the text box. The sheet is protected whilst allowing locked and unlocked cells to be selected. Both shapes are click active in this state.

Comment: Yes, you can't click the other shape until you are out of the first on.

Comment: Thanks @Davesexcel
Is there any work around to enable a user to input text then immediately click a button? Except of course from reverting back to using an active X textbox, which as it happens does work the way I want.

Comment: Why not to use a userform instead?

Comment: Is this so you can use xl online?

Comment: @Sgdva would that not mean using activex controls? I thought user forms only support activex but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Davesexcel no its for desktop use only.

Comment: It is but since they are within the sheet, it has the restriction that @Davesexcel stated. Quote: you can't click the other shape until you are out of the first on. If you do not want that, and basically from what you are saying: would not be better to just lock the sheet all together and control the input "outside" of it with a Userform?

Comment: It sounds like you either want a button to click that creates a `userform` or `InputBox()`; this would mean that you don't need information in the sheet, just a button to "get started".  Depending on what data is needed from the user, you will be able to pick the right data-collection method.

Comment: Thanks @Sgdva, with an activex text box it will work as expected in either the worksheet or a user form. I was just hoping I could switch to using form controls instead but it seams this limitation will mean I will have to revert to activex, at least for the text input. My application was currently setup using a worksheet with activex controls but I had some issues with the textbox resizing fonts etc.

Comment: Thanks @Cyril. I may have misunderstood the suggestion offered by Sgdva 
So if I'm understanding correctly the suggestion is to have a textbox shape on a user form, then a shape button on the worksheet, this I haven't tested. 
I will give that a try and let you know if that works.